# Passing CoreData content to a NSViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nstableview, nsviewcontroller

I've started to move to using NSViewControllers and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get content from a CoreData entity to a TableView (for example) through a NSViewController?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to associate a controller with the entity you are trying to pull data out of, and then use bindings to pull the rows from that into your table view.
There is a [core data tutorial](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000085.php) that explains everything quite well!
Also, the apple references for [core data](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/coredata.html) and [bindings](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html) are actually quite useful